# Varnish in kubernetes satefulset

Tags: varnish

I have deployed varnish in my k8s as deployments but I want to maintain state and don't want to lose cached data after pod restart. How do you do it - statefulset? is there a readily available helm chat available for k8s deployment for varnish 6?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately StatefulSets won't help you, because they don't seem to be freezing the memory that Varnish uses to store its cached objects. And even if it could, it would be quite tricky.

Because Varnish's native `file` stevedore does not support persistence and because it performs really poorly from a disk fragmentation point of view, the only real option is using [Varnish Enterprise's Massive Storage Engine](https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/features/mse/) feature.

I know that this is not an open source feature, but it's the only working solution I can come up with.